# How can I configure routing in my asp.new web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, post

I'm developing a 3-layer web app on asp.net web api. Now I have a trouble:
In my UI layer in HomeController I write next:

HomeController.cs

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        IPointService _pointService;
        IUserDataService _userDataService;

        public HomeController(IPointService pointService, IUserDataService userDataService)
        {
            _pointService = pointService;
            _userDataService = userDataService;
        }
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public string Plot(UserDataViewModel plotRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                var userDataDTO = new UserDataDTO { A = plotRequest.A, B = plotRequest.B, C = plotRequest.C, PointFrom = plotRequest.PointFrom, PointTo = plotRequest.PointTo };
                _userDataService.AddUserData(userDataDTO);
                List<PointDTO> pointDTOs = new List<PointDTO>();
                pointDTOs = _userDataService.Plot(userDataDTO);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pointDTOs);
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I debug my app I see that Plot function don't called out. But if I write the same func in other controller, it will have been called out:

PlotController.cs

```
    public class PointController : ApiController
    {
        public List<PointViewModel> _points = new List<PointViewModel>();
        IPointService _pointService = new PointService();
        IUserDataService _userDataService = new UserDataService();

        public PointController() { }

        public PointController(IPointService pointService, IUserDataService userDataService)
        {
            _pointService = pointService;
            _userDataService = userDataService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string Plot(UserDataViewModel plotRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                var userDataDTO = new UserDataDTO { A = plotRequest.A, B = plotRequest.B, C = plotRequest.C, PointFrom = plotRequest.PointFrom, PointTo = plotRequest.PointTo, Step = plotRequest.Step };
                _userDataService.AddUserData(userDataDTO);
                List<PointDTO> pointDTOs = new List<PointDTO>();
                pointDTOs = _userDataService.Plot(userDataDTO);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pointDTOs);
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

My POST in Index.cshtml:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '../api/Home/Plot',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(plotRequest),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                plotFunction(JSON.parse(data));
            }
        });
```

If I write `url: '../api/Point/Plot'` it will have been called out.

My RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Plot",
                url: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );
        }
    }
```

And my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Конфигурация и службы веб-API

            // Маршруты веб-API
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Plot" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I see that you didn't specify Plot controller in rouing tables. It could be a clue.

Comment: You should write `routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", ......` at the last.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining your routes correctly. first of all, when you define routes you must start from the specific to the generic:
here are your roots after changing:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Plot",
                url: "api/Home/Plot",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```